# Installing Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse

I am in the installation process for Eclipse Mars, followed the YouTube tutorials, but somewhere I went wrong. I realized that I have Eclipse installed, but for some reason when I click on the icon in /usr/share/applications , it opens up "Java EE - Eclipse". Did I not finish the installation process? Because by clicking the Eclipse icon in the /applications folder, it should open Eclipse itself.

Comment: How are you 'installing' it? In my experience, this app is 'installed' by giving it a directory to sit in and you run it by running the main executable

Answer (score 0):

'Java EE - Eclipse' list means you have the version of Eclipse for Java developers creating Java EE and Web applications.

There are several 'flavours' of Eclipse available of which this is one.

Open the 'Help > About' dialog to see more details about what you have installed.